# VMware Fusion 6: cannot start Windows 2000 VM that worked in VMware Fusion 4

Tags: windows, vmware, virtualization, macos

Got this message when starting a Windows 2000 VM on VMware Fusion 6 on a Retina MacBook Pro with OS X Mavericks:

> This virtual machine's policies are too old to be run by this version of VMware Fusion.

Could only find this [Danish question](http://notesnet.dk/notesnet/forum.nsf/0/0D27D4DCD6B9F3C5C1257A6B002BC33B?OpenDocument) with no answers.

Fusion 6 is supposed to

- [run any old virtual hardware version](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?cmd=displayKC&externalId=1022060) (this one is virtual hardware 7, I think it originates from VMware Workstation 6.5).
- [support Windows 2000](https://communities.vmware.com/thread/464500)
  Anyone having the faintest idea how to start digging for a cause?

*Edit: extra information about the settings, .vmx and .vmxf files.*

Opening the `settings` for this VM gets the same message.

[VMware Virtual Hardware version overview](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?cmd=displayKC&externalId=1003746).

There are a few lines with the word `policy` in the [.vmx](http://www.fileinfo.com/extension/vmx) file, but none in the [.vmfx](http://www.fileinfo.com/extension/vmxf) file. And there is a [.vmpl](http://www.fileinfo.com/extension/vmpl) file (which seems to have to do with the -now discontinued- [VMware ACE](http://www.vmware.com/products/ace/) that used to ship with older VMware versions [including VMware 6.5](https://www.vmware.com/support/ws65/doc/releasenotes_ws65.html)).

These are the lines with `policy` in the .vmx file:

```
tools.upgrade.policy = "upgradeAtPowerCycle"

policy.vm.mvmtid = "52 3f 1e 13 9d 44 69 76-7c dd cc d1 67 a4 46 32"
policy.vm.managedVMTemplate = "FALSE"
policy.vm.managedVM = "FALSE"
```

*Note*:

This is not a VMware Fusion specific question, searching for "[This virtual machine's policies are too old to be run by this version of VMware](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22This%20virtual%20machine%27s%20policies%20are%20too%20old%20to%20be%20run%20by%20this%20version%20of%20VMware%22)" (so without `Fusion` or `Workstation`) reveals some nice links including [Starting a virtual machine in Workstation or Fusion fails with the error: This virtual machine's policies are too old to be run by this version of VMware (2034362)](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=2034362) which also answers this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Open the virtual machine's configuration file `.vmx` using a text editor.
2. Remove the lines which starts with `policy.vm.*`:

   ```
   policy.vm.mvmtid = "52 d6 6f f9 f3 36 0f 9f-31 da 9f f5 90 7b ce 76"
   policy.vm.managedVMTemplate = "TRUE"
   policy.vm.managedVM = "FALSE"
   ```
3. Save the file and close the text editor.
4. Restart the VM.

---

If you still encounter the error…

1. Rename/delete the file with the extension `.vmpl`
2. Restart the VM.

For further reading, check out this thread: [VM's policies are too old to be run by this version](https://communities.vmware.com/message/2099362)

Comment: That's the thing: if I go to settings, I get the same message about policies.

Comment: Ok - then try remove the three police.x lines from the .vmx file - also see this thread: https://communities.vmware.com/message/2099362

Comment: Can you reword your answer by including the .vmx changes mentioned in your comment? Then I'll do some comment cleanup.